# Wikipedia: "Classification of discontinuities"

Tags: calculus

I've added an information to the Wikipedia article "Classification of discontinuities", but now I am in doubt if it's correct: "Intuitively, a function is continuous if (and only if) it has no breaks, jumps, vertical asymptotes, or wild oscillations."

Is it correct? (ignoring the fact I give no precise definitions for those terms... haha)

Thanks in advance to whoever help me. ^^

Comment: What do you mean by wild oscillations?

Comment: Like in f(x)=x sin (1/x).

Comment: You should specify it there in (may be in paranthesis).

Comment: Note that the archetypal examples of vertical asymptotes ($\frac1x$) and wild oscillations ($\sin(1/x)$) aren't discontinuous at $x=0$. They are undefined. A function can't be discontinuous at a point unless it's defined there.

Comment: Thank you guys. Now I understand it. It makes sense to me now. I will remove the information from there. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, if one extends $f(x) = x \sin\frac1x$ to be defined at $x=0$ by setting $f(0)=0$ then $f$ becomes continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: The intuitive way to comprehend a continous function is that one can draw it without lifting the pen. This is of course no rigorous definition , but a useful rule of thumb.

Comment: @Peter The problem is that that makes you believe that $f(x)=\frac1x$ isn't continuous, even though it is. It's a common misconception, but eventually becomes problematic.

Comment: @Arthur This function is not continous at $x=0$, since it is not defined there. At least  , I have often seen it treated this way. If this is defined in another way , then many mathematicians make that "mistake". Also, I learnt it this way in school , we distinguished between poles and removable discontinuities.

Comment: @Peter True. There is a difference between "discontinuous" and "not continuous". But "Show that $f(x)=\frac1x$ is continuous" is a standard introductory calculus exercise, and if you're too used to the "lifting the pen from the paper" notion of continuity, that exercise will confuse you.